# Mashalling in Ruby 2.2.0 slower than 2.1.5

Tags: ruby, performance, floating-point, marshalling

I have a complex object, my_object, which I marshal with

Marshal.dump(my_object)

I have benchmarked the performance of calling that line 100 times in both 2.1.5p273 and 2.2.0, and below are the results:

```
2.1.5  
                  user     system      total        real
Marshal Dump  7.310000   0.120000   7.430000 (  8.988470)
Marshal Dump  7.520000   0.050000   7.570000 (  8.210356)
Marshal Dump  7.610000   0.050000   7.660000 (  8.432685)

2.2.0
                  user     system      total        real
Marshal Dump 26.480000   0.150000  26.630000 ( 29.591742)
Marshal Dump 24.100000   0.300000  24.400000 ( 28.520397)
Marshal Dump 26.210000   0.210000  26.420000 ( 29.993412)
```

(I ran the benchmark 3 times for each version, to be thorough.)

As you can see, it's taking in excess of 3 times as long in 2.2.0 vs 2.1.5. I zeroed in on Marshal.dump because, using the ruby-prof gem, it showed me that that was the line that was performing poorly; but I can't find a way to get the methods that Marshal.dump itself calls in the profiler.

Edit: see my answer with a minimal repro, found after much experimentation

Comment: For those who want to follow this, I pared it down to a minimal repro, and logged it here: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10761.  The issue does not seem to be size  but rather complexity, as I had to created an object with many levels of nested objects within it to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The way you've edited that made the original question disappear and this question… well, it's not a question, it's basically an answer. I think the whole thing is interesting, but for SO standards I think it deserves a downvote.

Comment: @ian: Really? My choices were leave the question that didn't really help anyone, or post something that is, I'd argue, a pretty big deal, or delete the entire question.  I did what I felt was best for the community.  Honestly, it's pettiness like yours that gives geeks a bad rep.

Comment: Yes, really. It's not pettiness, it's how the site works. I came to this question and the original question is gone and an answer is in its place! If you have an answer, use an answer form. If you have edits to make to the question, edit it in a way that makes it clear. Often it just takes a line and the word *Edit:* with the further info.

Comment: I put it back the way it was, now mostly a waste of time and space, given that the now known root cause is quite specific and the original post is now mostly extraneous.  But rules are rules....

Comment: Space on the internet is infinite, don't worry yourself about it ;-) Have an upvote for a well formed and interesting question ^_^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69334/discussion-between-davej-and-iain).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source location is `nil`.

```
Marshal.method(:dump).source_location
#=> nil
```

This means that it is a C implemented method, and there is no more Ruby code that you can trace. In other words, it is an atomic/elementary method.

If you believe your result is valid, then I suggest you to post that as a bug in [Ruby trunk](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/issues). Several performance issues have indeed been found for the newest versions of Ruby, so your case does not seem unusual.

Comment: thanks for the technique and the suggestion.  Now begins the quest to find a tiny reproducible version of the problem!

Answer (score 1):

It's marshalling floats that causes the slowdown.

```
require 'benchmark'

class ToBeMarshaled

  def initialize n
    @a = []
    n.times do |i|
      @a << i.to_f
    end
  end

end

tbm = ToBeMarshaled.new(10000)

n = 100

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("Marshal Dump") {for i in 1..n; Marshal.dump(tbm); end}
end
```

results (ran benchmark 3 times for each Ruby version):

```
2.1.5
                  user     system      total        real
Marshal Dump  0.640000   0.010000   0.650000 (  0.744080)
Marshal Dump  0.670000   0.000000   0.670000 (  0.758597)
Marshal Dump  0.650000   0.020000   0.670000 (  0.747583)

2.2.0
                  user     system      total        real
Marshal Dump 25.070000   0.220000  25.290000 ( 27.980023)
Marshal Dump 24.100000   0.160000  24.260000 ( 26.633049)
Marshal Dump 24.440000   0.230000  24.670000 ( 27.540826)
```

~35 times slower.

If you take the ".to_f" off of that code, you get:

```
2.1.5
                  user     system      total        real
Marshal Dump  0.160000   0.000000   0.160000 (  0.180247)
Marshal Dump  0.180000   0.000000   0.180000 (  0.189485)
Marshal Dump  0.160000   0.010000   0.170000 (  0.191304)

2.2.0
                  user     system      total        real
Marshal Dump  0.120000   0.010000   0.130000 (  0.146710)
Marshal Dump  0.130000   0.010000   0.140000 (  0.159851)
Marshal Dump  0.130000   0.000000   0.130000 (  0.143917)
```

2.2.0 slightly edges out 2.1.5.